# How to set different servers across development lifecycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use thin server for development and unicorn for staging/production environments. How do I modify my Gemfile so that only the appropriate servers get installed in their respective gemsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In development:

```
group :development do
  gem "thin"
end
```

In staging and production:

```
group :staging, :production do
  gem "unicorn"
end
```